# What are some good approaches for stubbing dependancies in TDD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, stub

Let's say I'm writing a spec in Rspec for a Rails app and I'm stubbing out methods to reduce the number of dependancies in the spec:

```
# specs/account_statistics_spec.rb

describe AccountStatistics do
 it "gets the percentage of users that are active in an account" do
  account = Account.new()
  account.stub_chain(:users, :size).and_return(80)
  account.stub_chain(:users, :active, :size).and_return(20)

  stats = AccountStatistics.new(account)

  stats.percentage_active.should == 25
 end
end
```

It's now possible for the AccountStatistics spec to pass even if the `Account#users` and `User#active` methods are not defined in their respective classes.

What are some good approaches to catch the fact that the stubbed methods may not be implemented? Should it be left up to integration tests to catch the undefined methods? Or should the spec also check that the methods are defined before stubbing them?

It would also be great if someone can link to any good books / presentations which discuss stubbing and mocking in-depth :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your specific concern take a look at https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire to guard against stubbing non-existent methods.

I think the broader problem here is that you are not listening to the feedback trying to write this test is giving you. A test which is difficult to write is a good sign of either a poorly designed test subject or that the testing technique you are using is not a good fit.

What would this class look like if it did followed the law of Demeter (hard with ActiveModel relations)?
What would your test look like if you supplied a test double object instead of attempting to mock every method?
What would your test look like as an integration test?

I think the best resource for writing better tests is to look at the design of the code being tested instead. http://www.poodr.com/ might be a good resource. http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html is a good overview of test doubles you might not be considering while http://blakesmith.me/2012/02/29/test-stubbing-as-an-antipattern.html makes an argument for why mocks might be the wrong tool entirely. 
Specific to rspec http://betterspecs.org gives some hits what a good spec might look like. If those are hard to write that's a good hint that there's a broader problem.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using rspec-fire and removed the use of `stub_chain`. This way I felt comfortable that I was only stubbing out the values of existing methods and not the methods themselves. I completely agree about listening to the feedback from tests. Though in this instance I found the tests weren't difficult to write, rather I was concerned that they were making too many assumptions